# Tomcat GeoServer HTTP/2: ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: geoserver, java, tomcat, http, ssl

It is stated that Tomcat supports HTTP/2 (see [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http2.html)).

I have enabled HTTP/2 support in Tomcat 9.0.65 (see [doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#HTTP/2_Support)):

```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate 
               certificateKeystoreFile="conf/certs/domain.pfx" 
               certificateKeystoreType="pkcs12" 
               certificateKeystorePassword="" 
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Very often I get the error ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR as on GeoServer pages (most often on the Preview page) so it is on the server's home page.

I'm using AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.9.1, Tomcat 9.0.65, GeoServer 2.21.1

How to fix it?

PS: Log:

localhost

```
25-Aug-2022 17:57:23.204 SEVERE [https-openssl-nio-8443-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() для сервлета [dispatcher] в контексте с путем [/geoserver] выбросил исключение [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ResponseIOException: org.apache.coyote.CloseNowException: Connection [1], Stream [31], This stream is not writable] с первопричиной
    org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamException: Connection [1], Stream [31], This stream is not writable
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream.doStreamCancel(Stream.java:249)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.reserveWindowSize(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:898)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream$StreamOutputBuffer.flush(Stream.java:940)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Stream$StreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(Stream.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http2OutputBuffer.java:59)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:784)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:273)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.flushBuffer(Response.java:500)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.flushBuffer(ResponseFacade.java:312)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:181)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(GZIPResponseWrapper.java:140)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:181)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:181)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.flushBuffer(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:165)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.flush(ServletWebResponse.java:311)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.HeaderBufferingWebResponse.flush(HeaderBufferingWebResponse.java:99)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
        at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
        at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.service(StreamProcessor.java:426)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamProcessor.process(StreamProcessor.java:87)
        at org.apache.coyote.http2.StreamRunnable.run(StreamRunnable.java:35)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

tomcat9-stderr

```
25-Aug-2022 17:48:48.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.35] using APR version [1.7.0].
25-Aug-2022 17:48:48.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
25-Aug-2022 17:48:48.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:48.942 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.208 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.224 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-openssl-nio-8443"] connector has been configured to support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.224 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.536 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [824] milliseconds
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:49.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver.war]
25-Aug-2022 17:48:56.630 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Aug-2022 17:49:09.895 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver.war] has finished in [20 296] ms
25-Aug-2022 17:49:09.895 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Установка веб приложения в папку [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
25-Aug-2022 17:49:09.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [32] ms
25-Aug-2022 17:49:09.927 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2022 17:49:09.942 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
25-Aug-2022 17:49:09.942 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [20401] milliseconds
25-Aug-2022 17:50:35.973 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.020 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.077 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 WARNING [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [geoserver] appears to have started a thread named [FileSystemWatcher-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 WARNING [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [geoserver] appears to have started a thread named [JNA Cleaner] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 com.sun.jna.internal.Cleaner$1.run(Cleaner.java:58)
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 WARNING [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [geoserver] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
 com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
 com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
 com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.WTSEnumerateProcessesEx(Unknown Source)
 oshi.driver.windows.registry.ProcessWtsData.queryProcessWtsMapFromWTS(ProcessWtsData.java:86)
oshi.driver.windows.registry.ProcessWtsData.queryProcessWtsMap(ProcessWtsData.java:74)
oshi.software.os.windows.WindowsOperatingSystem.processMapToList(WindowsOperatingSystem.java:334)
oshi.software.os.windows.WindowsOperatingSystem.getProcess(WindowsOperatingSystem.java:311)
org.geoserver.system.status.OSHISystemInfoCollector.lambda$new$0(OSHISystemInfoCollector.java:76)
 org.geoserver.system.status.OSHISystemInfoCollector$$Lambda$514/0x00000001009e0840.run(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 WARNING [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [geoserver] appears to have started a thread named [EMF Reference Cleaner] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
 org.eclipse.emf.common.util.CommonUtil$1ReferenceClearingQueuePollingThread.run(CommonUtil.java:70)
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 WARNING [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [geoserver] appears to have started a thread named [GuavaAuthCache-0-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@11.0.9.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.9.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.base@11.0.9.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.jna.Structure$2] (value [com.sun.jna.Structure$2@d133f02]) and a value of type [com.sun.jna.Structure.StructureSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal.SuppliedThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal@19034f24]) and a value of type [org.geowebcache.storage.CompositeBlobStore.StoreSuitabilityCheck] (value [EXISTING]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1e42728f]) and a value of type [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl] (value [org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ffffffff: Null authentication]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.jna.Structure$2] (value [com.sun.jna.Structure$2@d133f02]) and a value of type [com.sun.jna.Structure.StructureSet] (value [[]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@555383b7]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@2ff9a995]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@22a270ef]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@56840c83]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@1f0363df]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@7d54d4ab]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@4cc0e6e6]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.582 SEVERE [Thread-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [geoserver] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1] (value [org.geotools.renderer.lite.RendererUtilities$1@65022a02]) and a value of type [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper] (value [org.geotools.referencing.operation.builder.GridToEnvelopeMapper@3ad61be9]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.598 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.613 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.629 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
25-Aug-2022 17:50:36.629 INFO [Thread-8] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
```

Comment: You'll need to look in the Tomcat log file to find out what the problem is, please add the relevant part to your questions

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should extend your `UpgradeProtocol` part

```
<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"                     
                 overheadCountFactor="-1"
                 overheadDataThreshold="0"
                 overheadWindowUpdateThreshold="0"
                 readTimeout="20000"/>
```

**Explaination**:

`overheadCountFactor` The factor to apply when counting overhead frames to determine if a connection has too high an overhead and should be closed. The overhead count starts at -10 * overheadCountFactor. The count is decreased by 20 for each data frame sent or received and each headers frame received. The count is increased by the overheadCountFactor for each setting, priority, priority update and ping frame received. If the overhead count exceeds zero, the connection is closed. A value of less than 1 disables this protection. In normal usage a value of approximately 20 or higher will close the connection before any streams can complete. If not specified, a default value of 10 will be used.

`overheadDataThreshold` The threshold below which the average payload size of the current and previous non-final DATA frames will trigger an increase in the overhead count. The overhead count will be increased by overheadDataThreshold/average so that the smaller the average, the greater the increase in the overhead count. A value of zero or less disables the checking of non-final DATA frames. If not specified, a default value of 1024 will be used.

`overheadWindowUpdateThreshold` The threshold below which the average size of current and previous WINDOW_UPDATE frame will trigger an increase in the overhead count (see overheadCountFactor). The overhead count will be increased by overheadWindowUpdateThreshold/average so that the smaller the average, the greater the increase in the overhead count. A value of zero or less disables the checking of WINDOW_UPDATE frames. If not specified, a default value of 1024 will be used.

`readTimeout` The time, in milliseconds, that Tomcat will wait for additional data when a partial HTTP/2 frame has been received. Negative values will be treated as an infinite timeout. If not specified, a default value of 5000 will be used.

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60049290/closenowexception-this-stream-is-not-writeable
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http2.html

Comment: Link-only Answers are generally down-voted and deleted, because links expire over time. When you write an Answer, you need to summarize the information within the linked pages, so that it can be found. The Answer should be standalone, with link only as supporting information; otherwise it may be converted into a comment or deleted.